# Scala: Is there a way to improve the timing performance of this convolution code?

Tags: scala, performance, convolution, timing

Good day to everyone.
I have been trying to improve the execution time of this code in Scala:

```
def TwoDimensionalConvolution(Input: => Array[Int], Height: => Int, Width: => Int, Kernel: => Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
  val R = (Kernel.length - 1) >> 1

  val result = Array.ofDim[Int](Input.length)
  for (i <- 0 until Height) {
    for (j <- 0 until Width) {
      var acc = 0
      for (k <- j - R to j + R)
        if (k >= 0 && k < Width)
          acc += Input(i * Width + k) * Kernel(k + R - j)
      result(j * Height + i) = acc >> 8
    }
  }

  val Output = Array.ofDim[Int](Input.length)
  for (i <- 0 until Width) {
    for (j <- 0 until Height) {
      var acc = 0
      for (k <- j - R to j + R)
        if (k >= 0 && k < Height)
          acc += result(i * Height + k) * Kernel(k + R - j)
      Output(j * Width + i) = acc >> 8
    }
  }
  Output
}
```

My code performs a two-dimensional convolution using the linear convolution of the rows and columns. Note that the input array is not two-dimensional, but the way to access it is linearly. The for loop of `k` allows you to iterate on each row or column without having to zero pad on edges.

I have also tried to avoid storing intermediate results as much as possible, but as you can see, the `result` variable, which saves the convolved rows, is necessary to perform the convolution of the columns.

I do not consider myself an expert in Scala and although I have some experience in C/C++, I can not improve the timing even more.

The truth is that I can not think of what else I could do with the few knowledge of functional programming I have.

Some Scala expert could suggest something to me?
Thanks in advance to everyone for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One optimization I would suggest would be to optimize the loop with k.
You have:

```
for (k <- j - R to j + R)
    if (k >= 0 && k < Height)
      acc += result(i * Height + k) * Kernel(k + R - j)
```

However, if `k is < 0 || k >= Height`, the loop does nothing and you are iterating needlessly.

Perhaps changing to:

```
for (k <- (j - R max 0) to (j + R min Height - 1))
     acc += result(i * Height + k) * Kernel(k + R - j)
```

This eliminates that `if` statement and ensures no extra iterations are consumed.

Comment: Truly, I would never have thought of replacing the if statement in the way you have done it within the for loop. Truly ingenious. I must say that thanks to your answer I am already very close (20%) to obtain the performance I am looking for, with respect to Scipy. I wish you could help me a little bit more with another clever observation like this.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely start by getting rid of by-name parameters (`: => ...`). They become functions which are evaluated on every use in the method, and even if you just pass variables and literals to the method call there is still non-trivial overhead.

Try replacing `for` loops with `while`. How much effect this will have will depend on Scala version and whether you pass optimization flags to the compiler. See e.g. http://dynamicsofprogramming.blogspot.com/2017/01/performance-of-scala-for-loops.html for comparison including Scala 2.12.

You also need to be careful when measuring performance: use [Scalameter](https://scalameter.github.io/) or [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. I will consider using while loops instead of for loops. I also got rid of by-name parameters; there's no performance difference.

Comment: This seems surprising. What is your Scala version and compiler arguments?